# `Date.UTC()` Doesnt work anymore on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I was working with the function `Date.UTC()` in my script and it was working great until I did an update to `Firefox`, after that update the browser returns `NaN` for that function as you can see in this image :

[image]

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) suggests that both the year and month are required.

```
Date.UTC(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]])
```

Note: month is 0 based, so if you want the beginning of the year, use 0.

Comment: I was about to post the exact same answer ;-)

Comment: thx it works now I used `Date.parse()` instead but I dont get it why it was working before the update without providing that second arg

Comment: It could be that the implementation allowed month to be optional or evaluated the `undefined` argument to be `0`.  In any case, it probably wasn't officially supported and the fact that it worked happened to be implementation dependent.  If your question is resolved, considering accepting an answer to mark your question as such.